# React + Reduxにおけるdispatch時のエラー

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

## React + Reduxにおけるdispatch時のエラー

### 概要

現在、TypeScript + React + Reduxを用いた開発を行っています。
仮のログアウト機能を実装中にエラーが発生しました。
具体的には、actionをdispatchした際にエラーが発生します。
どうやら下記のjwtLogout内のdispatchで発生している様です。
自分なりに色々調べてみましたが, connect等を用いた解決方法は見つかれど、Hooksを用いた解決方法が中々見つからず、今回は質問させて頂きました。
どなたか解決方法のご教授お願いいたします。

### エラーの内容

TypeError: dispatch is not a function

### 該当のコード

```
// reducer

import * as actionTypes from '../utils/actionTypes'
import * as actions from '../actions'

type Actions = (
    | ReturnType<typeof actions.startRequest>
    | ReturnType<typeof actions.completeRequest>
)

interface iState {
    isRequesting: boolean
}

const initialState: iState = {
    isRequesting: false,
}

const RequestReducer = (state: iState = initialState, action: Actions) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.START_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isRequesting: true
            }
        case actionTypes.COMPLETE_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isRequesting: false
            }
    }

    return state
}

export default RequestReducer
```

```
// actions

import { Dispatch } from "react"
import { Action } from "redux"
import * as actionTypes from "../utils/actionTypes"

export interface Actions {
    type: String;
    payload: any;
}

略 。。。

export const jwtLogout = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
        // TODO: gRpcログアウト && try-catch
        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.START_REQUEST })

        console.log('Logout')
        localStorage.removeItem('token')

        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.COMPLETE_REQUEST })
        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.UNAUTHENTICATE_USER })
        dispatch(setNotification('success', 'ログアウト成功！'))
    }
}
```

Comment: dispatch内のオブジェクトにpayloadも追加したほうが良いような気がします．dispatch({ type: ... , payload: ... })みたいな感じです．

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/236645

Comment: payloadも追加してみましたが、ダメでした…。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

放置して開発を進めていたところ、なぜか動作する様になりました…。恐らく他の部分の影響が出ていた模様…。
ありがとうございました！